# Cancel capitalization in python

Tags: python, capitalization

I am creating a program that you talk into, to give it a command which it then runs.  The problem is that when I run the program and I talk into it, it might capitalize some letters that I don't have capitalized in the code, so then it won't run the command.  Is there a way to make python not worry about if the words are capitalized? I have already tried capitalizing names but it seems to capitalize them when it wants to.
Code:

```
import speech
words = {"test1", "hello"}
test = speech.input("test: ")
tokens = test.split()
if words.intersection(tokens):
    print 'hi'
else:
    print 'test'
```

Comment: can you run `.lower()` on everything so capitalization just doesn't happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea: convert the input into lowercase *before* making any comparisons:

```
tokens = test.lower().split()
```

And make sure that all the elements in `words` are in lowercase, too:

```
words = { e.lower() for e in words }
```

By doing the above, we're comparing only lowercase characters throughout the program, so capitalization should not be a problem.